# react-native - unable to run sample app

Tags: react-native

Following the tutorial [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content), I am unable to run the app in the emulator.  When I execute the `react-native run-android`  command from the DOS prompt, here is the error I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
     Required by:
         :AwesomeProject:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/to
ols/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/bu
ild/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
               > repo1.maven.org
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools
/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build
/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

**Things I tried:**

1. Editing build.gradle file and changing classpath from classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3' to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0' (the version I have installed with Android Studio).
2. Verified that jcenter() is listed as a repository in build.gradle under both buildscript and allprojects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the project using the react-native cli, and the issue seemed to correct itself.  I should note that I believe I had not installed android studio when I initially created the project, so maybe that had something to do with it, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it to 2.3.0

Strange, I can't see any 2.2.3 in that path but I can see a 2.3.0
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/